# where to correctly free coroutine stack

Tags: webserver, coroutine

I am currently debugging a web server, just like Nginx, it is a master-worker structure. But there' s ome bug in it which i can't find.
when using address sanitizer, the server will crash over and over again due to access to invalid memory area.
heres the code :
https://github.com/JoshuaLee0321/cserv

My prof hinted me that it has something to do with `coro_stack_free`, yet i can't find a proper place to insert it.

i tried to insert the `coro_stack_free` function after the deletion of timer_node, it does not help.